# Can the locally 5-prism graphs be classified?

Tags: graph-theory

What it says on the label, pretty much.

If some graph $\Gamma$ is locally a 3-prism for all $ x\in\Gamma $, then it's easy to prove $\Gamma$ is the triangular graph $T(5)$.

If $\Gamma$ is locally the 4-prism (ie: the cube), it's not quite as easy to prove there's two different possibilities: the 24-cell, or the complement of a $3\times5$ grid (this only got done in 1983).

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X83901164

There's at least one graph that's locally an 5-prism: let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{31}$ (additively), $S=\pm\{1,2,4,8,16\}$mod $31$ and $ \Gamma = Cay(G,S) $. It has $v=31$, $k=10$, diameter $2$, and is symmetric but not strongly regular.

More generally, let $q=2^n-1$, $G=\mathbb{Z}_q$ and $S=\pm\{1,2, \dots 2^{n-1}\}$ mod $q$. Then $ Cay(G,S) $ is locally an $n$-prism for $n\geq4$. For $n=3$ this construction gives the complete graph $K_7$; for $n=4$ it gives the smaller locally cubic graph. (The 24-cell is exceptional, not for the first time.)

For composite $q$ (most Mersenne numbers are), if $r$ is a sufficiently large factor of $q$ the same construction also defines a smaller graph which is locally an n-prism. (Use $G=\mathbb{Z}_r$ and $S$ mod $r$.) (This is probably gonna end up as a different question, so here's a taster; $n=8$ and $r=51$ gives a 51-vertex graph that is locally an 8-prism, and there's generally a lot of graphs for each $n$.)

However, $2^5-1=31$ is prime (a Mersenne prime), so there's only one graph here. Are there more, smaller or bigger? If it's unique, can it be proven?